# How do I find the probability given this situation:

Tags: probability

I own a fleet consisting of X battle ships. Y of the ships in my fleet have malfunctioned and are launching missiles at friendly ships. Each day, so long as there is at least one malfunctioning ship, a normal ship will be destroyed by friendly fire. I, the captain come up with an ingenious solution: I will randomly destroy another ship every day until there are no malignant ships left, or until there are equal/more malignant ships than normal ships.
Each day: 1 good ship is destroyed, 1 random ship is destroyed. There are initially more good ships than bad ships.

> Q1: What is the probability in terms of X and Y that all bad ships are destroyed?
>
> Q2: What is the probability in terms of X and Y that I stop destroying ships due to equal/more bad ships than good ships remaining?

---

My attempt: I drew up a tree diagram, where intially there are (X-Y) good ships and Y bad ships. On day 1, outcome 1 is:
X-Y-2 vs Y
and outcome 2 is X-Y-1 vs Y-1

Day 2:
Outcome 1: [X-Y-4 vs Y] 2: [X-Y-3 vs Y-1] 3: [X-Y-3 vs Y-1] 4: [X-Y-2 vs Y-2]
So I've discovered that on Day T, there needs to be 2T ships missing to make 2^T outcomes.

Day 3:
Outcome 1: [X-Y-6 vs Y] 2: [X-Y-5 vs Y-1] 3: [X-Y-5 vs Y-1] 4: [X-Y-4 vs Y-2] 5: [X-Y-5 vs Y-1] 6: [X-Y-4 vs Y-2] 7: [X-Y-4 vs Y-2] 8: [X-Y-3 vs Y-3]
Now it appears that one far side will always have [X-Y-2T vs Y-0] on one side, and [X-Y-T vs Y-T] on the far other side. In between appears every possible sum of 2T.

Day 4:
1: [X-Y-8 vs Y] 2: [X-Y-7 vs Y-1] 3: [X-Y-7 vs Y-1] 4: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 5: [X-Y-7 vs Y-1] 6: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 7: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 8: [X-Y-5 vs Y-3] 9: [X-Y-7 vs Y-1] 10: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 11: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 12: [X-Y-5 vs Y-3] 13: [X-Y-6 vs Y-2] 14: [X-Y-5 vs Y-3] 15: [X-Y-5 vs Y-3] 16: [X-Y-4 vs Y-4]
Let 8vs0 denote as A, 7vs1 B etc, this pattern appears:
ABBCBCCDBCCDCDDE which has a form of symmetry to it.
Given that the previous day was ABBCBCCD, and the day before that was ABBC there is clearly a new proportion of X vs Y coming in each day. The number of each type might be important, so I'll find a rule for that first. On day 1 there was A and B. On day 2 there was 1A, 2B. 3) 1A, 3B, 3C, 1D 4) 1A, 4B, 6C, 4D, 1E which is clearly pascals triangle.

I don't really know if this information is at all helpful to me.

Comment: I tried a tree diagram and subbing X,Y for constants.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a simple formula, but here is a partial answer for a simple case: when the number of good ships is exactly one more than the number of bad ships, the probability of destroying all the bad ships without losing is $2^{-X}$.

The intuition is that you start with $U+1$ good ships and $U$ bad ships. First a good ship is destroyed, leaving you with $U$ good ships and $U$ bad ships. Then there is a 50% chance that you will destroy a good ship and lose the game, and a 50% chance that you will destroy a bad ship, leaving you in the same kind of situation you started in (one more good ship than bad) but with one less ship overall. You win if you can repeatedly destroy all $U$ bad ships in this way.

Edit: A few more suggestions.

1. First, the calculations might be neater if instead of the variables $X$ (total ships) and $Y$ (bad ships), you use $u$ (good ships) and $v$ (bad ships).
2. Second, it might be easier to start with a simplified version of the game where there is no friendly fire—you only destroy 1 random ship per turn. If $g(X,Y)$ is the probability of winning this simplified game, and $f(X,Y)$ is the probability of winning the original game, then you at least know that $f(X,Y)\leq g(X,Y)$ because the simplified game loses fewer good ships. It may also be easier to calculate $g(X,Y)$.
3. At least you have a recursive formula for the probability of winning the game: 
   $$f(u,v) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }u<v\\ 1 &\text{if } v=0\\ \frac{u-1}{u+v-1}f(u-2, v) + \frac{v}{u+v-1}f(u-1,v-1)&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$